# AAD graph API - add Microsoft accounts

Tags: azure-active-directory

In Azure AD graph API it is possible to create new users in your organizational directory.

Is it possible to add existing Microsoft accounts as users to your organizational directory? (This feature is available through Azure portal)

If yes, what would be the API call?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible today to do that programmaticay. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Is it on the roadmap at all?

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify and to add to what Vittorio said:

Yes, it is possible to create new users in your organization directory. The reccommended pathway to do this is with the Graph API. Note that these users will be users from the tenant you are creating them, not external users or MSAs. Check out our documentation here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#CreateUsers

Unfortunately we do not currently support creating MSA users or external users in your organizational directory. However, we are aware of this feature request, and it is on our backlog of to-do work items. You will likely see this as a feature that we expose via the Graph API, so keep a look out!

Thanks,
Shawn Tabrizi

Comment: Does anything have changed in this subject? Or it is still impossible to add external users from graph api.